# Actionmailer not sending email even though no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have a couple of different mailers setup on my system.  One is working fine and the other gives no errors but doesn't send out an email.

The mailer that works looks like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@footballpoolmania.com"

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.password_reset.subject
  #
  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password Reset"
  end

  def confirm_registration(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Confirm Registration"
  end
end
```

and when sending a password_reset email I get the following in the log:

```
Started POST "/password_resets" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-06 17:24:32 -0600
Processing by PasswordResetsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jwGUtsyNRbCfBRFJm3uqcVZA4luHc05Gf0OBm4jyFpI=", "email"=>"robertr2112@yahoo.com", "commit"=>"Reset Password"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'robertr2112@yahoo.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (2.7ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "password_reset_token" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 2  [["password_reset_token", "c851e80faeb3612c654c512857cfb29afc6a4665"], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Dec 2013 23:24:32 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (5.8ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (1.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (1.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "users" SET "password_reset_sent_at" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 2[0m  [["password_reset_sent_at", Fri, 06 Dec 2013 23:24:32 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Fri, 06 Dec 2013 23:24:32 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (1.6ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb (2.3ms)

Sent mail to robertr2112@yahoo.com (316.8ms)
Date: Fri, 06 Dec 2013 17:24:32 -0600
From: info@footballpoolmania.com
To: robertr2112@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <52a25cb0c52be_c94585623640840@debian.mail>
Subject: Password Reset
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

To reset your password, click the URL below.

http://localhost:3000/password_resets/c851e80faeb3612c654c512857cfb29afc6a4665/edit

If you did not request your password to be reset, just ignore this email and 
your password will continue to stay the same.

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 380ms (ActiveRecord: 13.7ms)
```

Also, the view for the message is defined as password_reset.text.erb and is located in app/views/user_mailer and looks like this:

```
To reset your password, click the URL below.

<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>

If you did not request your password to be reset, just ignore this email and 
your password will continue to stay the same.
```

The mailer that doesn't work looks like this:

```
class PoolMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "info@footballpoolmania.com"

  def send_pool_message(pool, subject, msg, allMembers)
    @pool = pool
    @msg = msg
    email_list = Array.new
    @pool.users.each do |user|
      if allMembers
        entries = Entry.where(user_id: user.id)
      else
        entries = Entry.where(pool_id: pool.id, user_id: user.id, survivorStatusIn:true)
      end
      if entries.any?
        email_list << "#{user.name} <#{user.email}>"
      end
    end
    subject_text = pool.name + ": " + subject
    if mail to: email_list, subject: subject_text
      puts "Successfully sent email"
      return false
    else
      puts "Couldn't send email"
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

And the log looks like the following:

```
Started POST "/pools/2/pool_messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-06 17:50:54 -0600
Processing by PoolMessagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jwGUtsyNRbCfBRFJm3uqcVZA4luHc05Gf0OBm4jyFpI=", "subject"=>"This is a test", "msg"=>"A test of the group pool message.", "allMembers"=>"false", "commit"=>"Send email", "pool_id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mPool Load (8.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "pools".* FROM "pools" WHERE "pools"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "2"]]
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.7ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "pool_memberships" ON "users"."id" = "pool_memberships"."user_id" WHERE "pool_memberships"."pool_id" = $1  [["pool_id", 2]]
  [1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."user_id" = 2[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."user_id" = 3
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."user_id" = 4[0m
  [1m[35m (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "entries" WHERE "entries"."user_id" = 5
  Rendered pool_mailer/send_pool_message.text.erb (0.7ms)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/pools/2
Completed 302 Found in 1527ms (ActiveRecord: 11.0ms)
```

And the view for this email is called send_pool_message.text.erb and is located in app/views/pool_mailer and looks like this:

```
<%= @msg %>

This is an automated email sent by the pool administer.  Do not reply to this
email.
```

The first mailer sends out the email correctly and logs it as well.  The second mailer neither sends an email or logs the email.  I'm not sure where to look to correct the problem because I get absolutely zero error messages on any of this.

Any help pointing me in the right direction to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the controller action that calls the mailer functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call .deliver to your mailer function

PoolMailer.send_pool_message(...).deliver

Otherwiser it just generates the email without delivering it

Comment: This probably isn't the answer. The OP says that the first iteration of the mailer successfully sends – it's only subsequent iterations that don't go through.

Comment: From what I understood, he's talking about the first type of mailer (UserMailer) not the first iteration

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé Thank you for the help!  I was so busy looking at all of the mailer items I totally missed the obvious problem!

Comment: Np! Happened to me often as well :)